# Why does the result from Sum not appear to be what partial sums converge to?

Tags: summation

Consider the following sum:

```
s[x_] = Sum[x^n*Log[x]^k*((n + k)/n!), {n, 0, Infinity}, {k, 0, n/2}]
```

and this partial sum:

```
f[x_, nMax_Integer] := Sum[x^n*Log[x]^k*((n + k)/n!), {n, 0, nMax}, {k, 0, n/2}]
```

When plotting them side by side, comparing as `f` converges to something with `s`, using the following code

```
    Manipulate[
 Plot[{Re@s[x], Im@s[x], Re@f[x, nMax], Im@f[x, nMax]} // 
   Evaluate, {x, -2, 2}, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"], {{nMax, 3}, 0, 
  100, 1}]
```

, for some reason I get completely different curves of real and imaginary parts. What's happening? Is Mathematica treating `n/2` in the upper limit of the sum over `k` in the series in some strange generalized sense of allowing `n` to be a half-integer? Is it actually expected behavior or a bug?

Comment: Mathematica does indeed not infrequently convert symbolic sums to certain analytical expressions when the upper limit is not explicitly a number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on my comment consider this example

```
f1[n_] = Product[i, {i, n}]
f2[n_] := Product[i, {i, n}]
(* n! *)
```

where the difference is only `Set` vs. `SetDelayed`.

[image]

as you can see, while the delayed version waits for a numeric `n` to inject into the `Product[]` and then behaves as iterators normally do in MMA, the undelayed version symbolically evaluates to `n!` which is evaluated via the gamma-function for non-integer arguments.

A similar intermediate evaluation is happening for your first function which is set undelayed.

Answer (score 2):

you may find this useful at least academically. we can rewrite the original form in terms of `m->n/2`, (taking pairs of terms for each `m` in the sum):

```
s[x_] := Sum[
  x^(2*m)*((k + 2*m)/(2*m)! + ((1 + k + 2*m)*x)/(1 + 2*m)!)*Log[x]^k,
  {m, 0, Infinity}, {k, 0, m}]
```

this agrees well with your finite `n` form. It is very slow so I'll just show a few values:

```
Table[{x, s[x], f[x, 100]}, {x, -1.9, 1.9, .5}]  // MatrixForm
```

[image]

This form can be evaluated for a symbolic `x` (use `=` instead of `:=` ). It is really unwieldy however ( many pages of `HypergeometricPFQ` terms ).

This blows up for integer x btw.

Edit:

manually simplifying a bit more yields a more reasonable analytic result:

```
s[x_] = Sum[
  x^(2*m)/(2*m)! *(k + 2*m + (k/(2 m + 1) + 1) x)*Log[x]^k, {m, 0, 
   Infinity}, {k, 0, m}] //FullSimplify
```

> [image]

now its fast enough to plot:

```
 Plot[{Re[s[x]], Im[s[x]]}, {x, -2, 2}]
```

[image]